# why the antd table added `+ ` automaticlly, how to remove the `+`

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd `"antd": "^3.26.3",` to develop a app, now the table have a `+` like this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI00y.png]

I did not add any setting to add the `+`, why the `+` come out? what should I do to remove the `+`? this is my antd table source code:

```
<div className={styles.tableList}>
            <StandardTable
              rowSelection={{
                type: 'checkbox',
                ...rowSelection,
              }}
              loading={loading}
              data={data}
              columns={this.columns}
              selectedRows={[]}
              rowKey="_index"
              hideAlert
              disablePagination={false}
              expandIconAsCell={false}
              expandIconColumnIndex={-1}
              onChange={this.handleStandardTableChange}
            />
          </div>
```

I have tried to add this config but still did not make the `+` disappear, what should I do to fix it?

```
expandIconAsCell={false}
expandIconColumnIndex={-1}
```

Comment: Does your `data` contains `children` property ? I think it is coming from there.\

Comment: yes, it contains children properties in my data. what should I do to avoid this problem?@SubratoPattanaik

Comment: Do you want to show the children data to the users? If not, then you can map your data to custom data with no children properties. If yes, then you need to figure out how you want to display those children data to users.

Comment: `expandable` api can help in customizing the children data.

Comment: I add this line `expandedRowRender={false}` and fix this problem, thank you, you save my time. @SubratoPattanaik

Comment: That's brilliant. I wasn't aware of it. You may write an answer to your question. 

Comment: I finally found add `expandedRowRender={false}`  did not work. Only remove the children properties works. Seems the only solution is to remove the children properties from the data. But I really want to show the children properties to the user, what should I do? @SubratoPattanaik

Comment: How do you want to display children data? children property is available to some object in the data array. what do you need instead of `+` to show the children data?

Comment: My children column does not mean the children data set, it means the user have children or not , it is a bool value, not a children dataset. @SubratoPattanaik

Comment: just alias the children to `haveChildren` during mapping your `data`  array dataset. If children is false, it will not display, if it is true, it will throw an error. I don't know how it works in your case. If children is an empty array it still show `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In antd Table component, `+` icon represents a row that can be expandable when clicked. By default, it is not expanded so when you clicked on `+` it will expand.

There are basically two cases in which `+` can appear in the rows of the table.

1. Using `expandable` api, `expandable` api allow us to render something things (data) by clicking `+` or anywhere in the whole row (this can be set by `expandRowByClick` as true). A common example for this case can be found [here](https://ant.design/components/table/?theme=dark#components-table-demo-expand).
2. Using `children` property in the `data` prop. [Example](https://ant.design/components/table/?theme=dark#components-table-demo-tree-data).
   Even if children property has an empty array, it will still show the `+` icon and when it is clicked it will expand with some extra spaces but no data in it.

Note: You should not use both the ways in one antd Table. So, you always have to choose one way over another depending upon the use cases.

---

In your case, you have mentioned that you have children property in your dataset which is a boolean value and has a different purpose than the children property of antd table dataset.

As I have mentioned in my comments, you just need to alias the children property to some other name, maybe `haveChildren` when mapping your dataset to a custom dataset.